# After finished viewing a certain page , have a js modal popup on the redirected page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I don't know how to do this. What I want is have a modal page appear after a user has finished viewing a certain page.

For instance, if a user is on `payment.html` they pay and get redirected to `feed.html`. On the `feed.html` page I'd like a thank you modal popup. But ONLY after the user has visited the payment page.

How can this be done?

Comment: 3 options: Get variables, Server-side conditional includes & Cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var entryPage = "payment.html";
   var referrer =  document.referrer; 
   if (referrer.indexOf(entryPage) >= 0){
      // Code to show modal goes here
   }
});
```

Comment: Within the if, I added ` $('#thanksModal').modal('show');
        console.log('thanks');`. It doesn't seem to work as it doesn't even show in the console. Any reason why it might not work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the syntax for a jQuery modal is just $('#thanksModal').show(); I would try a simple alert('is this working?'); in the if statement to see if it is reaching the code.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a session to keep track of the page visits.

If you don't want to show every time he loads any other page. 
at an included file
put the code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['visited']) && $_SESSION['visited'] = 1){
//show modal pop_up
```

$_SESSION['visited'] = '2';
    }

Comment: He explicitly indicated that he's using Python, not PHP.